# Comparing a list and dictionary and print it to YML file

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, yaml

I have list and dictionary, now I need to compare the keys within the dictionary with that of list and print the matching into a YML file.
So here is my dictionary keys,

```
samples1.keys()
dict_keys(['C3N-02289_10_L1', 'C3N-02289_10_L2', 'C3N-02671_08_L1', 'C3N-02671_08_L2','C3N-02671_10_L1','C3N-02671_10_L1' ])
```

And I have 2 lists,

```
Left_reads = [
    'C3N-02289_10_L1_R1.gz',
    'C3N-02289_10_L2_R1.gz',
    'C3N-02671_08_L1_R1.gz',
    'C3N-02671_08_L2_R1.gz',
    'C3N-02671_10_L1_R1.gz',
    'C3N-02671_10_L2_R1.gz'
 ]



 Right_reads = [
    'C3N-02289_10_L1_R2.gz',
    'C3N-02289_10_L2_R2.gz',
    'C3N-02671_08_L1_R2.gz',
    'C3N-02671_08_L2_R2.gz',
    'C3N-02671_10_L1_R2.gz',
    'C3N-02671_10_L2_R2.gz'
]
```

Now I need to compare each key which is in Dictionary (samples1.key) with values in lists (`Left_reads` and `Right_reads`). If the key matches the string in the list then print it to a YML file. 
Here is what I tried,

```
for sam in samples1.keys():
    ymlFile = pat + sam + '.yml'
    ymlFH = open(ymlFile, 'w')

    ymlFH.write("reads1: [\n")
    for sam in sorted(Left_reads):
        ymlFH.write(" {class: File, path: " + path + '/' + sam + "}, \n")
    ymlFH.write("]\n")

    ymlFH.write("reads2: [\n")    
    for sam in sorted(Right_reads):
        ymlFH.write(" {class: File, path: " + path + '/' + sam + "}, \n")
    ymlFH.write("]\n")
    ymlFH.close()
```

This prints outs all the values from lists `Left_reads` and `Right_reads` to the `reads1` and `reads2`.

I am aiming to have an output which prints each values in list sepertaly, as, for example,  for file `C3N-02289_10_L1.yml`, The output should look like, So here I have all values matching with `C3N-02289_10_L1` and C`3N-02289_10_L2`. I need the script to compare the prefix, that is here `C3N-02289_10`between the list and dictionary and then write to the YML file

```
reads1: [
 {class: File, path: /usr/path/C3N-02289_10_L1_R1.gz}, 
 {class: File, path: /usr/path/C3N-02289_10_L2_R1.gz},

]
reads2: [
 {class: File, path: /usr/path/C3N-02289_10_L1_R2.gz}, 
 {class: File, path: /usr/path/C3N-02289_10_L2_R2.gz},

]
```

The same for all values in the dictionary the matching strings from lists and so on.
With my above piece off code the output for `C3N-02289_10_L1.yml` looks like,

```
 reads1: [
     {class: File, path: /usr/path/C3N-02289_10_L1_R1.gz}, 
     {class: File, path: /usr/path/C3N-02289_10_L2_R1.gz},
    {class: File, path: /usr/path/C3N-02671_08_L1_R1.gz}, 
    {class: File, path: /usr/path/C3N-02671_08_L2_R.gz},
    {class: File, path: /usr/path/C3N-02671_10_L1_R1.gz},
    {class: File, path: /usr/path/C3N-02671_10_L2_R1.gz} , 
    ]
    reads2: [
     {class: File, path: /usr/path/C3N-02289_10_L1_R2.gz}, 
     {class: File, path: /usr/path/C3N-02289_10_L2_R2.gz},
    {class: File, path: /usr/path/C3N-02671_08_L1_R2.gz}, 
    {class: File, path: /usr/path/C3N-02671_08_L2_R2.gz},
    {class: File, path: /usr/path/C3N-02671_10_L1_R2.gz},
    {class: File, path: /usr/path/C3N-02671_10_L2_R2.gz} 
    ]
```

Comment: What is a YML file? There is something called YAML and  you should be using the `.yaml` file extension for that if possible (http://yaml.org/faq.html). And if you want to write that kind of files, always use a YAML library like `ruamel.yaml` or `PyYAML` (in case you only need to support the outdated YAML 1.1 specification).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's start with what your goal was.

In your code there is no comparison between the key in the dictionary and the values in the list. As I understand you want to check if the current dictionary key is the prefix of a value in a list and if so dump that filename to the `.yaml` file.

So your code should look something like:

```
for prefix in samples1.keys():
    for filename in some_list:
        if filename.startswith(prefix):
            # add the {class: File, path: some/path/filename } to the yaml file
```

Second the output of your code is not a valid yaml file.
I recommend using the `PyYaml` package.

if we put it all together we get:

```
import yaml

# definition of path variable is here somewhere...

# edited to take only the prefixes of the keys
desired_keys = ['_'.join(k.split('_')[:-1]) for k in samples1.keys()]

for prefix in desired_keys:
    yml_filename = prefix + '.yaml'
    reads1 = []
    for filename in Left_reads:
        if filename.startswith(prefix):
            reads1.append({'class': 'File', 'path': path + '/' + filename})

    reads2 = []
    for filename in Right_reads:
        if filename.startswith(prefix):
            reads2.append({'class': 'File', 'path': path + '/' + filename})

    data = {'reads1': reads1, 'reads2': reads2 }
    stream = open(yml_filename, 'w')
    yaml.dump(data, stream)
    stream.close()
```

On a side note I would recommend using the `os.path.join(path, filename)` method instead of `path + '/' + filename` just to make it less error prone.

### edit

With the given `Left_reads`, `Right_reads` and `samples1.keys()` the result are three `.yml` files:

`C3N-02289_10.yml  C3N-02671_08.yml  C3N-02671_10.yml`

where the first one, i.e. `C3N-02289_10.yml` contains:

```
reads1:
- {class: File, path: /path/yamlTest/__main__/C3N-02289_10_L1_R1.gz}
- {class: File, path: /path/yamlTest/__main__/C3N-02289_10_L2_R1.gz}
reads2:
- {class: File, path: /path/yamlTest/__main__/C3N-02289_10_L1_R2.gz}
- {class: File, path: /path/yamlTest/__main__/C3N-02289_10_L2_R2.gz}
```

Comment: This is throwing error as, TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-2fa09c274384> in <module>
     13 
     14     data = {'reads1': reads1, 'reads2': reads2 }
---> 15     stream = file(yml_filename, 'w')
     16     yaml.dump(data, stream)

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable. And more over the prefix is comparing to the whole list and returning everything within the list.

Comment: I don't get any errors. Are you running python 2.7?

Comment: I am trying on python 3

Comment: With the new edit still the error perexits: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-a96ebe13b6d8> in <module>
     19 
     20     data = {'reads1': reads1, 'reads2': reads2 }
---> 21     stream = file(yml_filename, 'w')
     22     yaml.dump(data, stream)
     23 

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: In my case output yml files do not show lines like you see.